# ASP-DropDownList CodeBehind images

Tags: html, asp.net, image, drop-down-menu

All I ever wanted is my DropDownList to be special. :(

I can write just names, but that won't be as intresting. So I tried to add images, like so:

```
// Somewhere in the code...
ListItem item = new ListItem();
item.Value = // something
item.Text = "<img src=\"" + <AnImagePathIGetFromTheDatabase> + "\">";
<MyDropDownlist>.Items.Add(item);
```

However the evil thing escapes the text in a list automatically, like so:

`&lt;img src=&quot;https://41.media.tumblr.com/bcb96f4a4c46a1001118ee216d7abacf/tumblr_mgfhbngsDl1r58qimo1_500.png&quot;&gt;`

So I get text instead of an image. How can I overcome this?

**EDIT**: Using  Lajos' solution, I've got to a situation where I inspect the selection element, And I get the following :

```
<img src="http://i.somethingawful.com/u/robtg/Fiesta/f05.jpg" alt="monster" height="42" width="42">
```

Which is pretty much what I was looking for. Sadly, in the page source, I get the following:

```
<option value="MeaninglessImp" class="imageconverter">http://i.somethingawful.com/u/robtg/Fiesta/f05.jpg</option>
```

The list itself shows 2 empty cells. The inspector says the pictures have been scaled down to 0x0.

Fiddle: [here.](https://jsfiddle.net/64wnewqn/)

Why does that happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the Text to contain the source and not show them until the page is loaded. You can implement a Javascript library which replaces src text with images in your list. That should solve the problem.

```
// Somewhere in the code...
ListItem item = new ListItem();
item.Value = // something
item.Text = <AnImagePathIGetFromTheDatabase>;
listItem.Attributes.Add("class", "imageconverter");
<MyDropDownlist>.Items.Add(item);
```

And in Javascript you need something like:

```
$(function() {
    $(".imageconverter").each(function() {
        $(this).html('<img src="' + $(this).text() + '">');
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you give an example to such a thing? I'm not sure what you're talking about.

Comment: I have edited my answer to add an illustrative example.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle with the generated html?

Comment: It seems you need to set the background-image with local images. (http://binnyva.blogspot.ro/2006/01/icons-for-select-menu-options-in.html)

Comment: I am happy to contribute